# Why does frequent garbage collection cause UI jank in spite of V8's blink scheduler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools

In the V8 blink rendering engine the scheduler only executes garbage collection during idle time. But why does Chrome dev tools document say:

> Spot frequent garbage collections 
>   If your page appears to pause frequently, then you may have garbage collection issues.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Garbage collection shouldn't affect the UI since its always scheduled to be in the remaining idle time of 60ms?

Comment: If there's a lot to collect and the operation cannot be split, it may exceed a frame span time.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you provide reference from Google official docs?

Comment: No, it's just something you can easily see in devtools performance analyzer.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you provide an example with code and performance analyzer screenshot.

Comment: No. Just imagine a slow CPU (like a mobile device) and a complex page that generates *a lot* of temporary objects.